# How to correctly set a path to default config for clickhouse backup?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-backup

I'm setting up [clickhouse-backup](https://github.com/AlexAkulov/clickhouse-backup) utility locally.
I go through the installation steps and now I'm stuck on the step with changing settings for '.config.yml' file.

I ran `sudo ./clickhouse-backup create` from the folder where I decompressed the utility and could found created backup in `/var/lib/clickhouse/backup`

When I execute:

```
sudo ./clickhouse-backup default-config
```

,I see the default settings.
Now I want to change a config file by adding credentials for ftp, s3 and so on.
What is the correct way of adding credentials to config file? I am not sure which file is being used.
Why I cannot find it in  "/etc/clickhouse-backup/config.yml" location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication for clickhouse-backup commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888261/authentication-for-clickhouse-backup-commands)

Comment: Not really, as I mentioned, I cannot find config.yml in this location `/etc/clickhouse-backup/`. There is no clickhouse-backup in etc. Maybe I missed some installation steps.

Comment: I can pass these parameters via docker command, as suggested in your other answer, but I want to hardcode them in the default file. And I don't understand why I cannot phisically locate `clickhouse-backup` in `etc` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./clickhouse-backup default-config` this command generates a template for the config with default settings.

try

```
sudo ./clickhouse-backup default-config > /etc/clickhouse-backup/config.yml

vi /etc/clickhouse-backup/config.yml
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually what I came to. I needed to create this folder explicitly.